# CSS animation start with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, hover

I have animation at https://jsfiddle.net/istcode/2cuj1owg/3/

```
<nav class="strokes">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="circle one"></div>
            <div class="circle2 two"></div>
            <div class="circle3 three"></div>
            <div class="circle4 four"></div> 
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I need to start **CSS** animation with **JavaScript** when a <*li> hover.(onmouseover)

When I go another <-li> animation should stop and reset.

I have 4 div for right animation. So I couldn't do with **JavaScript**.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: why JS ... simply apply animation on hover

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2cuj1owg/4/ like this ? hover and see

Comment: I don't think JavaScript is necessary here. It can all be done in pure css.